# Compilation issue with unicode character in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, utf

I was trying to compile a c++ file but I got the following error :

> > error C3850: '\uD800': a universal-character-name specifies an invalid character
> >
> > error C3850: '\uDFFF': a universal-character-name specifies an invalid character

The line having error is :

> > ValidateEmailAddr (L"\uD800\uDFFF@\uD800\uDFFF.com", false);

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: I suggest you to google the error before asking questions (Just copy and paste the first line in the Google search box). Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

The characters you specify are a surrogate pair - a pair of 16-bit quantites that together define one unicode code point (with value 0x103FF). The compiler is correct: this is not a valid code point, so you shouldn't be using it (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/103ff/index.htm).

If, despite this, you still want this value, you'll have to trick the compiler in some way. One possibility is to construct the value dynamically:

```
wchar_t bla [20];
bla [0] = 0xD800;
bla [1] = 0xDFFF;
...etc.
```

This is not as convenient, but really, the compiler is only trying to help you avoid an error here...